# What is the difference between converting vector components from Cartesian to polar, and converting the unit vectors?

Tags: coordinate-systems, transformation, polar-coordinates

To transform from a standard (2D) Cartesian coordinate system to polar coordinate system, we have the relations

$$ r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2},$$
$$ \theta = \arctan{\frac{y}{x}},$$

for the vector components. We also have the relations

$$ \hat{x}=\cos{\theta}\,\hat{\theta}-\sin{\theta}\,\hat{r},$$
$$ \hat{y}=\sin{\theta}\,\hat{\theta}+\cos{\theta}\,\hat{r},$$

for the unit vectors. If we  have an arbitrary vector $$\vec{v}=x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}$$ in Cartesian coordinates, what is the difference between transforming the vector using the first set of transformations, i.e.

$$ \vec{v} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,\hat{r}+\arctan{\frac{y}{x}}\,\hat{\theta}$$

and transforming the unit vectors using the second set of transformations, i.e.

$$\begin{align} \vec{v}& =x\left(\cos\theta\,\hat{\theta}-\sin\theta\,\hat{r}\right)+y\left(\sin\theta\,\hat{\theta}+\cos\theta\,\hat{\theta}\right)
\\ & = \left(y\cos\theta-x\sin\theta\right)\hat{r}+\left(y\sin\theta+x\cos\theta\right)\hat{\theta}\,, \end{align}$$

and why is one of these incorrect?

Comment: I just came across this question of yours, but do you now (after my answer to your other question) see where the confusing notation is taking place? And how all my remarks previously of being careful to distinguish a point $p = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) \in M = \Bbb{R}^2$ and the expansion coefficients  of the vector $v$: $v_x, v_y, v_r, v_{\theta}$ WITH RESPECT TO the (normalized) basis vectors $\{\hat{x}|_p, \hat{y}|_p\}$ or with respect to the (normalized) basis $\{\hat{r}|_p, \hat{\theta}|_p\}$ can be used to obtain the correct relationship?

Comment: (Also, strictly speaking, the formula for $\theta = \arctan(\dots)$ is only true in the first quadrant, because of how the inverse trig functions behave)... but this doesn't really affect the transformation behavior you're asking about

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with the fact that the first set of transformations are simply transforming the *components* of the vectors.  They are not vectors themselves, but they show how the components $(x,y)$ transform into $(r,\theta)$.  The second set of transformations shows how to transform a *basis* of the vector space into another basis.

Comment: So if one wishes to transform a vector from one coordinate system to another, one should transform the basis vectors and not the components?

Comment: @aRockStr Not quite.  You need to transform both.  When we write $(x,y)$ we're implicitly writing this in the basis $\hat{x}, \hat{y}$, but when we write $(r,\theta)$ we're implicitly writing this in the basis $\hat{r}, \hat{\theta}$.  In other words, when we write $(r,\theta)$ this isn't that we have a value of $r$ in the $\hat{x}$-direction, it is in the $\hat{r}$-direction.  Is this making sense?  To actually transform the unit vectors we need to do this with linear algebra.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. The notation $(x,y)$ in Cartesian coordinates does indeed correspond to $x\hat x + y\hat y,$ but the notation $(r,\theta)$ does not correspond to $r\hat r + \theta\hat\theta.$ The point at coordinates $(r,\theta)$ has position vector $r\hat r$ where the direction of $\hat r$ depends on $\theta.$ If you see $\hat r$ and $\hat\theta$ together it's probably for something such as a gradient or velocity at a particular point, not for a position vector.